# Prove that $m\leq 4$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

This question has been [cross-posted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379238/proving-that-m-leq-4) on Math.Overflow.

There are positive integers $a,b,c,d_i$, s.t. $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}}=\sum_{i=1}^m \sqrt{d_i}$, and for any $i\ne j$, $\sqrt{d_i/d_j}$ is not a rational number. Prove that, $m\le 4$.

I tried some algebraic transformations, such as
$$
a+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}=\left( \sum_{i=1}^m{\sqrt{d_i}} \right) ^2
$$
But they didn't work.

Would it be related to [Galois Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory)?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has already been [answered by @Fedor Petrov](https://mathoverflow.net/a/379315/131720) on Math.Overflow. And I think this can be accepted as a nice answer.